# Spring HibernateTemplate Saveor UpdateAll() replacement

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am  using Spring HibernateTemplate method SaveororUpdateAll(Collection cl) to insert 1000 records in every iteration.

As Method takes as collection and internally iterate every record and save it each record seperately.

Any other technique I can do a bulk insert or Update which require code changes and not effective with complex business rules.

Constraints : I don't wanna do bulk insert or bulkupdate as it requires code changes multiple places.and we have multiple business rules applied and It modifys CBO Object multiple times and store all objects in collecton while saving or inserting I want to replace HibernateTemplate SaveorUpdateAll(Collection) to improve performance.

Tried using BATCH_SIZE insert Update no improvement.

Thanks For your help.